# Guide me the best way of doing a task which takes a good amount of time to complete?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, time-complexity

In a asp.net web application we need to develop a page with following functionality:

- Read a text file containing around 1,00,000 coupon number.
- Create PDF for each coupon number and save it in a file server and also update database.

Its a time consuming process. If we do it in main thread it may occurs times out error. Please
guide me best approach to do this considering following points:

- Showing status of how may coupon has been generated and how much left.

Thanks,
paul

Comment: You'll have to run the job in a background thread or probably better as a separate service. It'll need to either write progress to the database or support being polled for progress so you can use that to update the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be best if you separate your time consuming tasks in a separate service(WCF service for example). You can create a method that will process your 10,000,000 coupons and generate PDFs and you can have another to check the status of the processing while just displaying a processing icon in your web page.

There are also other alternatives as [asynchronous pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) in asp.net.

Comment: my main concern is request time out error. as per my knowledge if any task takes more time than specified in executionTimeout it will throw error. Will WCF sevice or asynchronous pages overcome this issue?

Comment: Check out the task parallel library from .NET 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: finally i'hv done using TPL. BUT COULD NOT FIND A WAY TO CALLBACK ONCE PROCESS IS COMPLETED WITHOUT USING WAIT(). I have seen WAIT() make the page like synchronous. As a workaround a added one IsComplete field in JOB table and used that field to notify completion of the process. Anyway thanks for suggesting TPL. It is good...just i need to drive deeper into it.

Answer (score 1):

### Within Your Web App

If you must do this in your ASP.NET application, consider:

- [Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)

### Outisde Your Web App

If you'd want to move this out of your web app, you could submit a 'job' to another application like a web service or a Windows service. Simply give it the array of coupon numbers, or a file to pickup and parse.

For each coupon completed, it could drop that 'finished' flag into a database or a file to a directory, and your web application could read that for feedback to your user.